# My Splunk Timechart isn't returning any values

Tags: splunk

I'm running a splunk query and trying to generate my first timechart in a few years on a different splunk instance.

I made a query. And I can see that there is data. 2741 events

If I add to the query
| stats count
Then I see the 2741

But when I try to do a count
| timechart per_hour(_cd) as "count" span=1h

I don't get anything back.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

My query sucks

```
| timechart span=1h count as requests_per_hour
```